# Why is SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(4 arguments) trying to cast a CrossProcessCursorWrapper to a SQLiteCursor ? (ClassCastException)

Tags: android, sqlcipher

i am trying to log and fetch those logs in unit test in Android but i get a  ClassCastException inside

```
public Cursor rawQuery(String sql, String[] selectionArgs,
                       int initialRead, int maxRead) {
    SQLiteCursor c = (SQLiteCursor)rawQueryWithFactory(
                                                       null, sql, selectionArgs, null);
    c.setLoadStyle(initialRead, maxRead);

    return c;
}
```

Which is logical because rawQueryWithFactory, as the others rawquery methods, returns a CrossProcessCursorWrapper (implementing the Cursor interface).

```
public Cursor rawQueryWithFactory(CursorFactory cursorFactory, String sql, String[] selectionArgs, String editTable) {

//doing stuff

// CrossProcessCursorWrapper implements the Cursor interface as SQLiteCursor but is not of SQLiteCursor type.
return new CrossProcessCursorWrapper(cursor);
}
```

This code is from net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase ( Commit: c2aa13e490499482ab38075994cad327d2561749 [c2aa13e] ).

UPDATE :

Here is my code :

```
dbHelper = new LoggingRecordDBHelper(context, null);
db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase("pass"); 
Cursor cursor =  db.rawQuery(dbHelper.SQL_LOGGINGRECORD_SELECT_ALL, null);
```

And the logs:

> Running tests
> Test running started
> java.lang.ClassCastException: net.sqlcipher.CrossProcessCursorWrapper cannot be cast to net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteCursor
>
> at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1485)
>
> at com.eventmanagement.SQLCipherFetcher.getLogRecords(SQLCipherFetcher.java:31)
>
> at com.eventmanagement.ApplicationTest.testReadLogs(ApplicationTest.java:64)
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
>
> at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
>
> at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
>
> at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1738)

Comment: Are you using some contentprovider?

Comment: No, but the error does not happen in my code.

I'm doing
     dbHelper = new LoggingRecordDBHelper(context, null); 
     db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase("pass");
     Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(dbHelper.SQL_LOGGINGRECORD_SELECT_ALL, null);

Comment: seems like a bug in sqlcipher library ...

Comment: We have addressed this issue, more information can be found here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sqlcipher/7WnAgG14Yxc/_Fr9sD5mwxYJ

Answer (score 0):

This is an Error which is fixed in https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher/commit/d15b05edc773a0a7c3016bb6a91deec88f1fa7e7